# XML, PHP & XPATH - no results

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm having trouble using xpath and XML

This is an example of the XML file

```
    <OddService>
    <Header>
    <Status>000</Status>
    <Description>OK</Description>
    <Timestamp>1352407434</Timestamp>
    </Header>
    <Results>
    <Event>
    <EventID>1182745</EventID>
    <StartDate>2012-11-09T19:45:00</StartDate>
    <SportID>6046</SportID>
    <LeagueID>1182547</LeagueID>
    <LocationID>243</LocationID>
    <Status>NSY</Status>
    <LastUpdate>2012-11-08T20:27:14.767</LastUpdate>
    <HomeTeam ID="7" Name="Middlesbrough" Logo=""/>
    <AwayTeam ID="992" Name="Sheffield W" Logo=""/>
    <Scores status="" time=""/>
    <Scorers/>
    <Cards/>
    <Outcomes>...</Outcomes>
    </Event>
    <OddService>
    <Header>
    <Status>000</Status>
    <Description>OK</Description>
    <Timestamp>1352407434</Timestamp>
    </Header>
    <Results>
    <Event>
    <EventID>1182745</EventID>
    <StartDate>2012-11-09T19:45:00</StartDate>
    <SportID>6046</SportID>
    <LeagueID>1182547</LeagueID>
    <LocationID>243</LocationID>
    <Status>NSY</Status>
    <LastUpdate>2012-11-08T20:27:14.767</LastUpdate>
    <HomeTeam ID="7" Name="Middlesbrough" Logo=""/>
    <AwayTeam ID="992" Name="Sheffield W" Logo=""/>
    <Scores status="" time=""/>
    <Scorers/>
    <Cards/>
    <Outcomes>...</Outcomes>
    </Event>
    </Results>
    </OddService>
```

On this XML example, I've only included one of the entries. I'm using this PHP Code, but getting no results... does anyone have any ideas?

```
    <?php
    $loadfile = simplexml_load_file('matches.xml');

    foreach ($loadfile->OddService->Results as $gameinfo):
    $kodate=$gameinfo->StartDate;
    $status=$gameinfo->Status;
    $id=$gameinfo->EventID;
    $league=$gameinfo->LeagueID;
    $hometeam=$gameinfo->HomeTeam['Name'];
    $awayteam=$gameinfo->AwayTeam['Name'];
    $home=$gameinfo->Outcomes->Outcome->Bookmaker->Odds[0]['currentPrice'];
    $away=$gameinfo->Outcomes->Outcome->Bookmaker->Odds[1]['currentPrice'];
    $draw=$gameinfo->Outcomes->Outcome->Bookmaker->Odds[2]['currentPrice'];
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah sorry, someone missed that bit off!

Comment: $xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');
 
 $fixtures = $xml->xpath('/OddService/Results');
 //    $loadfile = simplexml_load_file('games2.xml');
 
 
    foreach ($fixtures as $gameinfo):

Comment: Your XML string is malformed, it looks like it's missing one or two closing tags

Comment: This is my XML page: http://www.mynap.co.uk/matches.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying your XML file - after adding the root node myself - and it works OK. The only issue I see is that not all Results nodes have an Outcomes node, so you'll get an error when PHP runs the last three lines inside the foreach loop. You can fix that with this:

```
if ( $gameinfo->Outcomes ) {
    $home=$gameinfo->Outcomes->Outcome->Bookmaker->Odds[0]['currentPrice'];
    $away=$gameinfo->Outcomes->Outcome->Bookmaker->Odds[1]['currentPrice'];
    $draw=$gameinfo->Outcomes->Outcome->Bookmaker->Odds[2]['currentPrice'];
}
```

Other than that, it should work... Have you tried to `var_dump`'ing $gameinfo inside the loop?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback.

Thing is, if I remeove the following from the XML, it works fine

Comment: <OddService>
<Header>
<Status>000</Status>
<Description>OK</Description>
<Timestamp>1352413846</Timestamp>
</Header>

......

</OddService>

Comment: I would need to see more code, perhaps the complete set from where  you load your XML up to where you do something with the result... Your XML file works just fine on my side...

Comment: Why don't you just create a jsfiddle and store the code there, then post the URL here? That way everyone else can see it :)

Comment: First time I've used jsfiddle, but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/krischambers/HN8rp/

Comment: Ok, a couple more observations: it gives me some "variable undefined" errors, also, some complaints about the use of `<?=$variable?>` syntax, it's better to use something like `<?php echo $variable; ?>` instead, also, opening php tags should be `<?php` instead of just `<?`... after fixing and/or commenting out most of those, I had no problems with both your code and your xml file... why do you say you get no results? What have you tried to debug this code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no xpath in that code... however, when you load an XML, the root is already included, so you probably need to change your foreach to

```
foreach ($loadfile->Results as $gameinfo):
```

Comment: By the way, my XML file is as follows:

It's hosted elsewhere, this is just a copy - 

http://www.mynap.co.uk/matches.xml